# Getting different errors each time - trying to upload and merge multiple csv

Tags: python, pandas, datatable

```
import time
import datatable as dt
print(dt.__version__)

df_2016_1 = dt.fread("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\City of Toronto - Parking Data\Parking_Tags_Data_2016_1.csv")
```

ERROR 1

```
 File "<ipython-input-31-e1b12aa55c73>", line 5
    df_2016_1 = dt.fread("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\City of Toronto - Parking Data\Parking_Tags_Data_2016_1.csv")
                         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

```
import time
import datatable as dt
print(dt.__version__)

df_2016_1 = dt.fread("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\City of Toronto - Parking Data\\Parking_Tags_Data_2016_1.csv")
```

ERROR 2

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-50d21994b471> in <module>
----> 1 df_2016_1 = dt.fread("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\City of Toronto - Parking Data\\Parking_Tags_Data_2016_1.csv")
      2 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datatable/utils/fread.py in _resolve_source_file(file, tempfiles)
    197             return _resolve_archive(xpath, ypath, tempfiles)
    198         else:
--> 199             raise ValueError("File %s`%s` does not exist"
    200                              % (escape(xpath), escape(ypath)))
    201     if not os.path.isfile(file):

ValueError: File /content/C:\Users\HP\Desktop\City of Toronto - Parking Data\Parking_Tags_Data_2016_1.csv does not exist
```

I'm looking to upload 25 csv files and merge them to one single dataframe

I tried to use datatable as its faster

When i try to read the first csv it gives unicode error as below. I tried alternating with \ and forwarslash as well as adding "r" in front of it. When i try these i get the second error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, so you have to use `/` not `\`:

```
df_2016_1 = dt.fread("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/City of Toronto - Parking Data/Parking_Tags_Data_2016_1.csv")
```

Comment: Still the same error after using /